# when I update android studio I get: failed to apply patch

Tags: android, android-studio

when I update the android studio from version 2.2.1 to version 2.2.2, I always get the following error:
Failed to apply patch

Comment: Are you using windows OS ? If yes, then run android studio as administrator and then try to update it.

Comment: Try to temporarily disable Windows Defender or any other antivirus/firewall/security software.

Comment: I tried both methods but not ok

Comment: May be some of you studio files don't have write permission, which is wrong. Try to set read and write permission to your studio folder and other is studio's config folder.  You can find studio config folder as '.studio' in my document as hidden. Try and let me know...

Answer (score 1):

Try Below solution

1) Run Android Studio As Administrator.
2) Close every open project.
3) Goto Task Manager End/Kill JAVA Process.
4) Now in Android Studio

Start up Panel ...
goto Config > Check For Updates

. And when dialog appears .press update and restart.

-as stated by [nightcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5456671/nightcoder)

---

When updating JVM's heaps size was set to -Xmx500m.

I ran upgrade command in cmd(launch as admin) with -Xmx2048m .

```
C:\LMS\bin\jdk****\jre\bin\java -Xmx2048m -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -classpath  C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio_copy;C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\log4j.jar.AndroidStudio_copy;C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\jna.jar.AndroidStudio_copy;C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-utils.jar.AndroidStudio_copy -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ -Didea.updater.log=C:\Users\XXXX\.AndroidStudio1.2\system\log -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel com.intellij.updater.Runner install "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```

I ran the above script after downloading the patch & when it asks for install options . This worked for me.

- By [uhs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2753994/uhs)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You are modified files by paths from this dialog. If it is the logs files, you can remove it, else - you should backup it from another place.
That problem was reprodused on macOS and Windows by me.

Comment: from where to modify the path? from which dialog?

Comment: Where are you seen this error? Can you attach any screenshot/log to your question?

Comment: configure ----- check for update ------ update and restart, then the downloading stage, then validating installation, thenapplying patch, I got:

Comment: I got failed to apply patch

Comment: Temp. directory: C:\Users\Active\AppData\Local\Temp\

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)

Comment: at com.intellij.updater.Utils.copyStream(Utils.java:166)
 at ie.wombat.jbdiff.JBPatch.bspatch(JBPatch.java:83)
 at com.intellij.updater.DiffAlgorithm$JBDiffAlgorithm.applyDiff(DiffAlgorithm.java:102)
 at com.intellij.updater.DiffAlgorithm$JBDiffAlgorithm.applyDiff(DiffAlgorithm.java:86)

Comment: at com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.applyDiff(BaseUpdateAction.java:106)
 at com.intellij.updater.UpdateAction.doApply(UpdateAction.java:47)
 at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:188)
 at com.intellij.updater.Patch$3.forEach(Patch.java:333)
 at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:385)
 at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:328)
 at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:84)
 at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:75)

Comment: at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:289)
 at com.intellij.updater.Runner$1.execute(Runner.java:255)
 at com.intellij.updater.StandaloneSwingUpdaterUI$5.run(StandaloneSwingUpdaterUI.java:191)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)